# Updating Google KMZ Popup Contents & Removing "Directions" in FME

Tags: kml, arcgis, kmz, fme

By default a KML balloon will contain links "Directions to Here" and "Directions from Here" (driving directions).

I want to know, how to remove these links from the balloon using FME, as well as use HTML to set KML Balloon content, URL links and images, such as pngs, jpegs, and tiffs.

Also, I will appreciate if there is a workaround other than FME, to do the same, my objective is to remove the data from google kmz which I don’t need and only want to show that data which is required.

Answer (score 0):

What you will want to end up with in the KML file is a BalloonStyle for your balloon content, which looks like: `<BalloonStyle><text>...</text></BalloonStyle>`, either shared at the top of the KML file, or inline in each placemark/feature.  Your BalloonStyle can contain with either static HTML/Text content for the balloon, or an HTML template that can be filled in with basic data (name, description, etc.) or ExtendedData fields from each feature.   When you specify balloon content using BalloonStyle, it will leave leave out the directions info.  It will also not include the name at the top of the balloon by defautl, so you may want to include that in your content or template.

For more on KML BalloonStyles, see:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#balloonstyle

and:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/extendeddata

I don't know much about FME, but looks like it's possible to do this using AttributeCreator. For more see these instuctions:
https://community.safe.com/s/article/kml-balloon-contents-removing-directions